# flutter Problem: How to update number of items count in cart?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

### I implement to add to cart functionality items added into cart successfully but the number of count in the cart badge is not updated when I reload dart page  than the number of count updates.can anyone help me?

I implement to add to cart functionality items added into cart successfully but the number of count in the cart badge is not updated when I reload dart page  than the number of count updates.can anyone help me?
This is my Homepage.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:badges/badges.dart';
import 'package:hospital/BestDeatProducts/best_deal_product_page.dart';
import 'package:hospital/CartPage/pages/cartPage.dart';
import 'package:hospital/Drawer/dropdown_menu.dart';
import 'package:hospital/FirstSection/carousel.dart';
import 'package:hospital/Drawer/drawercontent.dart';
import 'package:hospital/FloatingActionButton/ConsultWithDoctor/consult_with_doctor.dart';
import 'package:hospital/MedicineCateory/medicine_category_page.dart';
import 'package:hospital/SecondSection/second_page.dart';

import 'package:hospital/ThirdSection/third_page.dart';
import 'package:hospital/TrendingProducts/trending_product_page.dart';
import 'package:hospital/constant.dart';
import 'package:hospital/customApiVariable.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

import 'No Internet/connectivity_provider.dart';
import 'No Internet/no_internet.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  SharedPreferences loginData;
  // late String username;

  Future getUsername() async {
    loginData = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      // print("uname" + uname.toString());
      print("dddpppuu1 : responceData_un" +
          loginData.getString('responceData_un').toString());
      print("dddpppuu2 : responceData_ue" +
          loginData.getString('responceData_ue').toString());
      print("dddpppuu3 : responceData_status" +
          loginData.getString('responceData_status').toString());
      String responceData_uid =
          loginData.getString('responceData_uid').toString();
    
      fetchData(responceData_uid);
    });
  }


  var response;

  var addToCartApi;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    //
    super.initState();

    Provider.of<ConnectivityProvider>(context, listen: false).startMonitering();
// for loading
    getUsername();
  }

  fetchData(String argResponceData_uid) async {
    var api = Uri.parse(
        '$ecommerceBaseUrl/addToCartApi.php?a2rTokenKey=$a2rTokenKey&action=addToCartList&uid=${argResponceData_uid}');
    print('cartpage' + api.toString());

    response = await http.get(api);

    print("Carousel" + response.body);

    addToCartApi = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print('addToCartApi' + addToCartApi['total'].toString());

    print('totalPriceAfterOffer' + totalPriceAfterOffer.toString());

    setState(() {});
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: kGreen,
          title: Text(
            "BK Arogyam",
            style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
          ),
          actions: [
            
            response != null
                ? Badge(
                    position: BadgePosition.topEnd(top: 3, end: 18),
                    animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                    animationType: BadgeAnimationType.slide,
                    badgeContent: Text(
                      addToCartApi['total']['num'].toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    child: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 30.0),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Cartpage()),
                          );
                        }),
                  )
                : IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
                    // onPressed: () => print("open cart"),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Cartpage()),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
            DropDownMenu(),
          ],
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: kGreen,
          onPressed: () => Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ConsultWithDoctor())),
          tooltip: 'Consult With Doctor',
          child: Container(
            child: Image(
              image: AssetImage(
                "assets/icons/cwd.png",
              ),
              color: Colors.white,
              width: 40,
              height: 40,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        drawer: Drawer(
          child: DrawerContent(),
        ),
        body: pageUI());
  }

  Widget pageUI() {
    return Consumer<ConnectivityProvider>(
      builder: (consumerContext, model, child) {
        if (model.isOnline != null) {
          return model.isOnline
              ? ListView(
                  children: [
                    Carousel(),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10.0,
                    ),
                    MedicineCategoryPage(),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10.0,
                    ),
                    SecondPage(),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10.0,
                    ),
                    ThirdPage(),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10.0,
                    ),
                    TrendingProductPage(),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 16.0,
                    ),
                    BestDealProductPage(),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10.0,
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              : NoInternet();
        }
        return Container(
          child: Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Check out [ask] to improve this question

Answer (score 1):

You can use the change notifier provide by provider package.

And watch the video on how to use, exactly for ur use case search YouTube change notifier provider by the growing developer

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use provider(provider: ^5.0.0) or Getx(get: ^4.1.4) to handle this kind of case.
There are lots of examples are available for GetX and Provider.

If you don't want to use any of them, Then store your cart/badge count to tempCartCount variable(Example: int cartCount = 0) and set it to the badge count instead of "addToCartApi['total']['num'].toString()" , Make sure to setState on update/addCart Item.

Here I provide a simple example of how to update count on appBar.

if you want to change from any other screen make cartCount to global otherwise you can set it local/private.

```
import 'package:badges/badges.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class UpdateCountExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UpdateCountExampleState createState() => _UpdateCountExampleState();
}

int cartCount = 0;

class _UpdateCountExampleState extends State<UpdateCountExample> {
  List<String> cartArray = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      setState(() {
        cartCount = 0;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("App Bar"),
        actions: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 18.0, top: 5.0),
            child: Badge(
              badgeContent: Text(cartCount.toString()),
              child: Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              "Add item in cart",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18, decoration: TextDecoration.none, color: Colors.black),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  cartArray.add("value ${cartArray.length}");
                  cartCount = cartArray.length;
                });
              },
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                color: Colors.amber,
                child: Text(
                  "Add Item",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, decoration: TextDecoration.none, color: Colors.black),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: cartArray.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Text(
                      cartArray[index],
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black),
                    );
                  }),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the problem that how will the cart be updated in setState?

Comment: You want to update only the cart badge count in the app bar am I right? @Deepak

Comment: yes I want to update only the cart badge count in the app bar.

Comment: please check the example I added for the change badge in the app bar. I hope it's useful @Deepak

Answer (score 0):

I have used StreamBuilder to update cart items instantly.

You can use the code from this post
[How to use Streambuilder in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72413847/how-to-use-streambuilder-in-flutter/74912898#74912898)